# How do I get the username and number of pokes of given to a specific user id from database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

After a user logs in to my django application. The User can poke another User in the database. How can I get the User firstname of the poker and number of pokes they gave to a specific User in the database? Below is my code.

This is how I get the number of times a User has been poked in html template. Please help.
{{ i.pokegotten.all | length}}

```
    class User(models.Model): 
         firstname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
         lastname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
         email = models.EmailField(max_length=45)
         password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
         bday = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
         created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
         updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
         objects = UserManager()

    class Poke(models.Model):  
         poker = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name= "pokegiver")
         poked = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name= "pokegotten")
         created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
         updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
         objects = PokeManager()
```

Comment: here pakegotten.all will give you entire count .... i think you need  changes in your model

Answer (score 0):

to get poke giver firstname, (from your question it seems you may have same user multiple time as a poker)

```
get_firstName = Poke.objects.filter(pokegiver=request.user)
if get_firstName:
    firstName = get_firstName[0].pokegiver.firstname
```

similarly, 
if it is user specific:

```
get_poked_count = Poke.objects.filter(pokegotten="user object").count()
```

get entire count,

```
get_poked_count = Poke.objects.all().count()
```

Comment: I think it will give error as `firstname` should be `pokegiver__firstname`.